# chrome.executeScript is sometimes not executing the script file passed as argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have the following code through which I am trying to execute a script in response to a successful ajax call triggered through popup.js. I see no errors in background script console, popup console or the page console.

---

Popup.js

```
        GetPageImages = function (tabID, inputVariables) {
                console.log(1);
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabID, { file: jqueryFile }
                  , function () {
                    console.log(2); 
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabID, {
                        code: 'var inputVariables = ' + JSON.stringify(inputVariables)
                    }, function () {
                        console.log(3);
                        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabID, { file: filePath }, function () {

                        });
                    });
                });

        }


        $http.post(baseURL + "api/Update").
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    GetPageImages();

                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("Failed to save the page");
                });
        }
    }]);
```

I can see that the files I want to get executed through function GetPageImages are executed sometimes, but sometimes they are not. I am not able to figure out what could be the reason behind it, could be the thread calling executeScript is getting exited or this is a behavior of executeScript. How do I investigate this?

---

On Adding logs as updated in the code, I can see only `1` getting printed in the console. Also, if I check content scripts on the page, my file (jquery file), that is the first one to be executed, is not seen on the page.

Comment: Try adding `console.log(1)`, (2), (3) before each executeScript and see where it stops. BTW what is the advantage of using promises here?

Comment: Nothing. I was just trying something and forgot to remove from here, updating the question

Comment: Just updated in the question. I can see no logs from the success functions, though sometimes when successful I see logs for 1, 2 and 3. This ambiguity is something weird

Comment: By success callbacks, I meant success callback for executeScript. If 1 is getting printed that implies GetPageImages() is getting called which implies $http.post success callback is called

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87753/discussion-between-labyrinth-and-woxxom).

Comment: Can you try explicitly setting `"run_at"` to `"document_end'` or `"document_start"`? See the chatroom for more details.